# Windows Workflow Designer - Customized layout and icons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm looking for a way to customize Windows Workflow Designer in a way that the layout of the components and their icons is more intuitive and user friendly, something similar to LabView NI-LabView , where the number of inputs and outputs to a certain component (could be a re-used workflow) is shown on the screen and each input port is data type aware, meaning that it accepts a certain data type and rejects invalid types.

I have re-hosted the workflow designer in my WPF application and I want to give this functionality to the end user to be able to design new workflows, reuse them and use their newly created workflows in my application.

I would appreciate if you could point out possible solutions, components or alternatives to this approach. I am open to using MS Robotics VPL as well, if it can meet these requirements.